# Less accesiable than method

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            student s = new student();

            foreach (var item in p.ab())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.id+item.name+item.fname);  
            }

        }

        public  List<student> ab() 
        {
            List<student> l = new List<student>()
              {
                 new student{id=1,name="hjk",fname="xyz"},
              };
            return l;
         }

        class student
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String fname { get; set; }
        }
```

**Inconsistent accessibility**:

> return type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   is less accessible than method 'ConsoleApplication7.Program.ab()'

Comment: try to add some description , what you want to achieve? Thats how this website works.

Comment: `student` is a `private` class of which you are returning a list of from a `public` method. That's not allowed.  The return types of public methods must be public.

Answer (score 3):

Add public in class declaration---- return type  is `List<student>` less accessible than method(method is public )  so u need to make type as public

```
public class student
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String fname { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Too fast, i was coming to post the same. anyway congrats ++ :)

Answer (score 1):

You main method should be wrapped inside public class

student should be public

check the following snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            student s = new student();

            foreach (var item in p.ab())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.id+item.name+item.fname);  
            }

        }

        public  List<student> ab() 
        {
            List<student> l = new List<student>()
              {
                 new student{id=1,name="hjk",fname="xyz"},
              };
            return l;
         }

}
 public class student
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String fname { get; set; }
        }
```

Hope this helps